# PHP/MySQL - Select based on another result

Tags: php, mysql

Hey people, looking for some help here.

Basically I have two tables in a MySQL database, `jobs` and `dates`.

Each date references a job by id, sometimes more than one date reference a single job.

I'm doing this query (`x` being a variable integer):

`SELECT * FROM jobs LIMIT x,50`

Now I have a result with 50 job-records and I would like to retrieve all dates pointing to these 50 jobs in one query.

How can this be done without iterating over the result and making a query for each iteration?

Hope I was clear enough :S

PS: Didn't manage to draw a decent table with a little mysql structure.

Comment: A+ for not going the iteration route, I've spent this week painfully fixing several needlessly deep query iterations from past developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM jobs
INNER JOIN dates
    ON dates.job_id = jobs.id
LIMIT x,50
```

This would limit it to ONLY those jobs that DO HAVE dates associated with them.  So if you want to see jobs that might might not have dates associated, use an OUTER join:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM jobs
LEFT JOIN dates ON dates.job_id = jobs.id
LIMIT x, 50
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can do this.

1. Use the **IN** keyword.

   ```sql
   SELECT * 
   FROM dates 
   WHERE job_id 
       IN (1, 2, 3, 4, ..)
   ```
2. Select it all at once.

   ```sql
   SELECT * 
   FROM jobs 
   LEFT JOIN dates 
       ON jobs.job_id = dates.job_id 
   LIMIT x, 50
   ```

That will give you a row for each (job, date) combination, with potentially multiple jobs for each date.